# What does B:B mean in Excel?

Tags: excel, operators

I am working with Excel and met a function like this: COUNTIF(B:B,B347)>1

I don't known what does **B:B** in the function mean?

Please help me if anyone known, Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

B:B refers to all cells in column B